# Restrict Delete Specific User in yii2-user

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I'm using `yii2-admin` and `yii2-user`. I've created a role `Creator` who have access to the everything. There is another role called `Admin` who have limited access. But have the power to delete users. Now I want to restrict `Admin` from deleting `Creator`. I know that this can be achieved by overriding the `delete` function of the `AdminController` of `yii2-user`. But I cannot figure out the logic of restricting `Admin` or any other user from deleting `Creator`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-control-filter
The only thing that you need to do is to limit the access to the delete function to people who have the Creator role. All others will not be able to delete anything.

your function should look like

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
........
                    [
                        'actions' => ['save', 'update', 'status', 'activate-all', 'deactivate-all'], // Define specific actions
                        'allow' => true, // Has access
                        'roles' => ['Admin', 'Creator'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['delete', 'delete-all'], // Define specific actions
                        'allow' => true, // Has access
                        'roles' => ['Creator'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => false, // Do not have access
                        'roles' => ['?'], // Guests '?'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

This is just an example, modify it to suit your own needs. Probably you should not allow an Admin to edit a Creator too as changing the password would be almost the same thing as deleting.

Comment: I think you didn't get me. I want that users that have access to the admin panel should be able to delete other users but not the ones with `Creator` role.

Comment: I was thinking of another way to do it. By hiding the users with `Creator` role from the grid view. And this should happen only if the logged in `user` does not have the `Creator` role. Any ideas on how do it?